# invalid resource directory name: "assets" for running an mp3 file in the second activity

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I wrote this code in VS 2012 into C#

```
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.house);
    mPlayer.Start();
```

This code is run in `MainActivity` but it is not run in the second activity. I have this error:

```
invalid resource directory name: "assets"
```

Comment: This is question related to c# or android?

Comment: I wrote this code in VS 2012 for android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your files from assets you have to do

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength();
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

**Let  me know if it is not working**

Comment: I saw [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335856/xamarin-how-to-set-videoview-to-black) and I changed your code to run in C# but I saw this error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) File: house.mp3

Comment: There is not that error but now I saw this error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object when I run this code after clicking a button. And quality of mp3 file is bad, why?

Comment: This error also disappeared. I had 8 buttons in MainActivity and one button in the second activity. I changed name of the ninth button and this error disappeared.